# When does Class#getClassLoader return null?

Tags: java, null, classloader

Say I have some Java code:

```
public class Widget {
    ...whatever
}
```

And some code that classloads the `Widget`:

```
ClassLoader widgetLoader = Widget.class.getClassLoader();
```

Can `widgetLoader` ever be `null`? Why/why not? If so, under what circumstances?

Comment: I'm not fully sure on this, but I would have to say it can and can't be. If there are items in the class, then I guess it would mean that it wouldn't return null, but if it was an empty class, it probably might return null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this method [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29):

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use
>   null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
>   null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29

Comment: well, it's newer.. I know it doesn't change anything, but better stick with what is up to date ;)